# How to Use or Import jQuery custom builder in a Notepad, Sublime etc...

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask how to use the jquery custom builder since i separate the folder of jquery custom builder to the Login Folder. Here is the folder path for the jquery custom builder [image: Jquery Custom BUilder]

And here is for the Login Folder

[image: Login Folder]

I have tried this kind of syntax for getting the Directory of the js file and to other files to but it doesn't seems to work.

```
<script src = "‪../htdocs/WebSite/jslib/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

i hope you can help me with this since i'm just starting jquery i also read the guide for using jquery i follow the instruction but it's still the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the html file that imports jquery script tag? It seems like just path problem. Usually, URI paths are based on app server root. There are so many ways managing URI, but XAMPP might let file resource paths show up same as URI paths.

When app server root is located on `c:/foo/bar/`:

- `c:/foo/bar/lib/jquery.js` -> `http://localhost:xxxx/lib/jquery.js`
- `c:/foo/bar/index.html` -> `http://localhost:xxxx/index.html`

So in `index.html`, import resource as this way.

```
<script src="‪lib/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: but what if the index.html is in another file ? would the code be like for importing the .js ?

Comment: what is index.html file path exactly?

Comment: ‪C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php this is the file path for the index .

Comment: so, if it makes sure index.html has importing script tag, have you tried `src="WebSite/jslib/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"`?

Comment: if `src="/WebSite/jslib/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"` (absolute path from app root) also doesn't work, I have no advice for you. I am sorry it didn't help you.